# Mix DDR3 RAM Late 2015 iMac

Tags: imac, hardware, memory

I want to add RAM to the existing RAM in my iMac 5k Retina Late 2015.

The memory I want to use is the [Corsair - 8GB (2PK x 4GB) 1000 MHz DDR3 SoDIMM Laptop Memory Kit](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/corsair-8gb-2pk-x-4gb-1-0ghz-ddr3-sodimm-laptop-memory-kit-green/2824528.p?skuId=2824528)

If I mix that RAM with the existing RAM,  it Will  be 16GB and 8GB with Apple RAM. Can this be done? It’s DDR3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is the incorrect speed for your iMac.

You need 204-pin PC3L-14900 (1867 MHz) DDR3 SO-DIMMs
Something like this:
[https://www.amazon.com/Micron-PC3L-14900-DDR3-1866MHz-Unbuffered-MT8KTF51264HZ-1G9E2/dp/B071ZFJ81K](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071ZFJ81K)

Also, check you have free slots available (your Mac has 4 slots total) - check in Apple menu-> About This Mac-> System Report... then select the Memory option to view what you currently have installed.

You can mix new RAM with existing RAM, the speeds must match though.